# NullReference Exception was unhandled in foreach

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, smo, stringcollection

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MyProject.exe
>   Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

It says ,
**StringCollection** strCol is null,
but **table.Script()** is not null (it includes the record).
It does the foreach only once. When it comes for a second time it gives this exception.
Here is my code:

```
foreach (var item in Sourceclb.Items)  
{
    Table table = database.Tables[item.ToString()];
    StringCollection strCol = table.Script();//Gives exception here
    var script = "";
    foreach (var key in strCol)
    {
         script += key;
    }
    command.Connection = ttbl;
    command.CommandText = "USE "+_hedefDb+" \n EXEC sp_sqlexec '"+scriptdondur(script)+ "'";

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    txtLog.AppendText("*TABLE COPIED* "+item.ToString()+" has been copied. \r\n");
}
```

Comment: You have a null item in the string collection

Comment: I've figured it out but then Why It works for once and then stops working? :<

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do

`foreach (var item in database.Tables)`

rather than

`foreach (var item in Sourceclb.Items)`

Not all the items in `Sourceclb.Items` will be tables, and as soon as you hit one that isn't, `database.Tables[item.ToString()]` will return null, with the consequent NullReferenceException at `table.Script()`.